# Get alias addresses associated to an email address

Tags: web-apps, email

I am trying to look for a means to interrogate an email address to receive any associated aliases to the address. Is this possible?

I would imagine a Third-Party API would be involved in this however I haven't managed to find anything that would even come close to what I am trying to accomplish.

In short all I need is a service of which I can pass up the email address and receive a list of alias email addresses linked to the account.

Comment: I am not aware of any company that collects this kind of information, but I guess some are doing it. If they offer it as a service, it will probably cost money and the information will probably be very spotty.

Comment: Apart from being spotty (and questionable as long as you request details on a domain not hosted by the same provider – as how should the provider know then, without having access to the mail server?), I'd consider such service a privacy breach, probably even including legal implications (depending on country).